# Writing a file from memory in C

Tags: c, memory, zero

I have been trying to write a file from memory in C, more specifically an executable file. Every time I try to use `fputs` it detects a '00' in memory after a bit and stops writing. But there is still the rest of the file that it has to write. In the file that I am trying to write there are '00's all over the place for padding. I have some code below for reference:

```
char *buffer;
buffer = malloc(size);
// ...
FILE *file;
file = fopen("somename","w");
fputs(buffer,file);
fclose(file);
```

Is there any way I would be able to have '00's in memory without `fputs` taking it as an EOF?

Thanks!

Comment: `strcpy(buffer,"Hello");` `fputs(buffer,file);`

Comment: Use fwrite and explicitly tell length to write

Comment: Use [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) to write the raw binary data? The [`fputs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) function writes a ***null-terminated*** string, and a zero byte is the null-terminator. And if the goal is to write the raw binary data contents of the memory then I suggest you open the file in binary mode.

Comment: what does your `buffer` contain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use 'fwrite' take the place of fpus